# Showing shadow in a cell inside table view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Inside a table view, Is there any way to show a shadow in a specific cell? I want to show shadow in the last cell of my table view. Rest of the cells should be normal.

I am using the following code but the shadow is coming after my cell is finished. I want the shadow to be at the beginning of my cell:

```
[self.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
[self.layer setShadowOpacity:1];
[self.layer setShadowRadius:1.0f];
[self.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:50.0 green:70.0 blue:56.0 alpha:0.5].CGColor];
[self.layer setShadowPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, -44, 320.0,20)] CGPath]];
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by shadow. With what code would you set the shadow for any cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change your cell in the `-[tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]` method of your tableviews's datasource.

Check if the `indexPath.row` is the last row in your tableview. If it is not, return table view cells as usual. Otherwise, return a cell with the shadow. It is probably best to have a different reuseIdentifier for the cell with the shadow (see the docs for UITableViewCell and UITableViewDataSource for more details).

Comment: That is ok. But I was using the following code but the shadow is coming after my cell is finished. I want the shadow to be at the beginning of my cell:    [self.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
  [self.layer setShadowOpacity:1];
  [self.layer setShadowRadius:1.0f];
  [self.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:50.0 green:70.0 blue:56.0 alpha:0.5].CGColor];
  [self.layer setShadowPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, -44, 320.0,20)] CGPath]];